# OS X Mojave ModuleNotFoundError for pip and conda

Tags: macos, pip, anaconda, conda, macos-mojave

Since I have installed OS X Mojave to my MBP I get a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to use conda or pip. Does anyone have the same problem?

```
File "/Users/stfn/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: Try: `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1`